# JQuery-bootgrid can't turn html table into bootgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, jinja2, jquery-bootgrid

When I call `$("#grid-basic").bootgrid()` in either the HTML HEAD, the table does not transform on page load. When I call it in the javascript console, I get `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).bootgrid is not a function(…)`. This table is being loaded by Jinja2, if that changes anything.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the bootgrid plugin is not loaded in your HTML head (you may have loaded it in your body).

I got the same error when my script was loaded in the body and not head of the page.